# Javascript React: Push to an array in useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to store an array of strings in the state object under the key of `menuHistory`, im initialising it with 'first', when the page changes `props.location` updates, that triggers the useEffect() where I then try to push the location into the array.

The error I'm getting is..

```
Argument of type '{ menuHistory: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ menuHistory: string[]; }>'.
  Type '{ menuHistory: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ menuHistory: string[]; }'.
    Types of property 'menuHistory' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2345)
```

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

interface propsInterface {
    location: any; 
  }

const SideMenu: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props) => {
  const { global } = useContext(Context) as {global: any; setGlobal: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>};
  const [state, setState] = useState({menuHistory: ['first']});

  useEffect(() => {
    const location = props.location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    setState({menuHistory: state.menuHistory.push(location)});
  }, [props.location])

  return (
    <div className='nav'>
        <Link to={{pathname: '/my/identity'}}><div id='identity'>Identity</div></Link>
        <Link to={{pathname: '/my/accounts'}}><div id='accounts'>Accounts</div></Link>
        <Link to={{pathname: '/my/claims'}}><div id='claims'>Claims</div></Link>
        <hr/>
        <Link to={{pathname: '/my/profile'}}><div id='profile'>Profile</div></Link>
        <Link to={{pathname: '/my/password'}}><div id='password'>Password</div></Link>
        <Link to={{pathname: '/my/settings'}}><div id='settings'>Settings</div></Link>
        <Link to={{pathname: '/my/logout'}}><div id='logout'>Log out</div></Link>
  </div>
  );
}

export {SideMenu};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like @Clarity said, `push` returns index of pushed item, also this operator mutates object. Best practice is to create another array (eg. by spreading previous value, like suggested), and add a new entry there, like so:

```
setState({menuHistory: [...state.menuHistory, location]});
```

Answer (score 2):

`push` return an index of element, use array spread to add the item:

```
setState(state => ({menuHistory: [...state.menuHistory, location]}));
```

Comment: the error has changed to `
(
</li>
Argument of type '(state: { menuHistory: string[]; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ menuHistory: string[]; }>'.
  Type '(state: { menuHistory: string[]; }) => void' is not assignable to type '(prevState: { menuHistory: string[]; }) => { menuHistory: string[]; }'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ menuHistory: string[]; }'.ts(2345)`

Comment: @Bill I've updated the answer to return the object properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined {menuHistory: ['first']} which is array .
Try using concat instead of push.

```
   setState({menuHistory: state.menuHistory.concat(location)});
```